# I'm able to connect to my seafile using my root domain, although I only specified to use my subdomain. (nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, subdomain, cloud

I have the following problem, that I'm able to connect to my seafile installation using my root domain "www.domain.com", although I only specified and I only want to use "cloud.domain.com". I only have access to one server IP, maybe that's the problem?

Accessing "www.domain.com", doesn't redirect me to the subdomain it just opens a session on the root domain.

My A Records are setup like this:

- www.domain.com > serverIP1
- domain.com > serverIP1
- cloud.domain.com > serverIP1

My nginx.conf:

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name cloud.domain.com;
rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {

listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cacert.pem;    
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;   
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;

server_name cloud.domain.com;

 location / {
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
    fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS   on;
fastcgi_param  HTTP_SCHEME https;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
}       

location /media {
    root /root/cloud/seafile-server-1.7.0.2/seahub;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know `nginx`...but it looks like in your `rewrite` statement there's nothing matching on the lefthand side so `$1` will be empty on the righthand side.

Comment: do you have a server definition for a `default` domain? This is done with `listen <port> default`

Comment: No, but I just tried adding    listen 80 default;    but I still was able to connect to my seafile installation using www.domain.com.